# EMF Induced in a portion of a Loop by time varying Magnetic Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

Here I understand that they are asking about the EMF Induced in the Portion **AOB**. 
 
I do know how to calculate the Induced EMF for the whole Circular Loop, but for shape like this, I am struggling a bit, which makes me feel that I don't have conceptual clarity over here. 
 
So, I would be really grateful if someone suggest me how to tackle this kinds of problems.

Comment: For the closed path BOAB, Faraday's law says induced EMF is given by rate of change of magnetic flux through this closed path. So first, you need to figure out magnetic flux through closed path BOAB. Then, to answer the question, you need to find induced EMF $\mathscr{E}_{AB}$ in the path segment A$\to$B and subtract it. Hint: draw a triangle AOB and calculate EMF for this triangle via the flux method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming symmetry, you can find the emf in a circular loop of radius, r, (with its center at the center of the field). That gives, E, as a function of, r.  Integrate that from, A, to , B, to get the emf in the straight segment of the semi-circle. Subtract that from the total emf in the semi-circle to get the emf along the curved segment.